# replaceAll does not seem to be working with regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I want to replace all the characters in a string that are not alphanumeric or that don't belong to a special character list that the user inputs.

```
String pagePath = "/content/geo/en/tool";
String specialCharacters = "\\:*?\"<>|#";
String fileName = pagePath.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}^\\p{IsDigit}\\:*?\"<>|#]", replacer); //This works fine o/p: ~content~geo~en~tool

String test2 = "\"[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}^\\p{IsDigit}" + specialCharacters + "]\"";
String fileName2 = pagePath.replaceAll(test2, replacer);
```

For some reason the value of fileName2 remains, /content/geo/en/tool

Can someone please help me out with what is going wrong?

Comment: You have extra `"` at start and end of your `test2` (probably automatically escaped by your IDE). To see why two regexes are not working the same try printing them so you could compare their content.

Comment: Voting to close as copy-paste typo.

Comment: BTW `^` represents negation only at start of character class `[^..]`. If you place it in the middle it will be treated as simple literal.

Comment: BTW2 ``\\`` even inside character class `[...]` is metacharacter, so `\\:` represents escaped `:`. I am not sure what your intention was, but `:` is not metacharacter so it doesn't require escaping, so if that was what you ware trying to achieve then ``\\`` is redundant (which makes your regex more confusing than it should be). If it wasn't your goal then you should allow regex to escape all these character via `Pattern.quote(specialCharacters)`.

Comment: \\ was in order to escape \. I will be using Pattern.quote like you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to escape the quotes in `test2`:

```
String test2 = "[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}^\\p{IsDigit}" + specialCharacters + "]";
```

Comment: Questions caused by typographical errors (like wrong copy-paste area) can't help anyone except OP which means that they are off-topic on Stack Overflow. I know that it looks like easy reputation points, but at some point such question have great chance of being deleted along with reputation earned on it which may leave you with negative balance. at some day. So instead of posting solutions as answers feel free to post them as comments which would allow OP to delete it (as long as there will be no upvoted/accepted answer).

Comment: Ok. To be honest, didn't think of it as a typo in the first place.

Comment: I doubt OP would put it there deliberately. But many IDEs automatically escape `"` when pasting string which suggests copy-paste mistake, which IMO is example of typographical error.